# Trying to integrate Phonegap Connection API with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use [PhoneGap Connection API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_connection_connection.md.html) inside my Angular/Ionic project. What I want is to check the user's network and if it's NONE I want to show a specific **div** and if it's not NONE, show another **div** by using the *ng-show* directive.

Here is my code so far:

**controller.js**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, CheckConnection) {

     $scope.net = CheckConnection.networkState();

})

.factory('cordovaReady', function() {
    return function (fn) {

        var queue = [];

        var impl = function () {
        queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    };

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        queue.forEach(function (args) {
        fn.apply(this, args);
    });
    impl = fn;
    }, false);

   return function () {
       return impl.apply(this, arguments);
   };
 };
})

.factory('CheckConnection', function(cordovaReady) {
    return {
        networkState: cordovaReady(function() {
            var net = navigator.connection.type;

            if(net == 'none') {
                var internet = false;
            } else {
                var internet = true;
            }

            return internet;
        })  
    };  
})
```

**view.html**

```
<ion-nav-view name="login">
    <div ng-hide="LoginCtrl.net">
        NO CONNECTION {{net}}
    </div>
    <div ng-show="LoginCtrl.net">
        CONNECTED {{net}}
    </div>
</ion-nav-view>
```

I'm pretty new with Angular and PhoneGap so this issue may be very simple to solve but I just can't figure it out :( Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution! Angular has it's own way to check connection so I don't even need PhoneGap for this.

Here is my new **controller.js**:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($window, $scope ) {
     $scope.online = navigator.onLine;
     $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
         $scope.$apply(function() {
             $scope.online = false;
         });
     }, false);
     $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
         $scope.$apply(function() {
             $scope.online = true;
         });
     }, false);
})
```

And **view.html**

```
<ion-nav-view name="login">
    <div ng-hide="online">
        NO CONNECTION
    </div>
    <div ng-show="online">
        CONNECTED
    </div>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Hope it helps someone else :D

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ion-nav-view name="login" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
<div ng-hide="net">
    NO CONNECTION {{net}}
</div>
<div ng-show="net">
    CONNECTED {{net}}
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a .js to control the states of my project and there I defined the LoginCtrl as the view.html controller. So there is no need to declare ng-controller in the html. Sorry